# Could jasmine browser runner work with terminal reporters? Or other way for test output

Tags: jasmine

Working with Jasmine with tests. To tests I used jasmine-browser-runner
like this `jasmine-browser-runner runSpecs --config=spec/config/jasmine-browser.json`
It works fine but in the terminal, I have dots .... and F.
To output nice results in the terminal, I've tried those npm packages
`jasmine-spec-reporter` and `jasmine-console-reporter` but they run in node and don't see web functions (like performance and other parts of the app because I do not use module.export and require)
Tried Jasmine Standalone configuration with jasmine-reporters from this repo https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v3.8.0</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-3.8.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-3.8.0/jasmine.css">
  <script src="../reporter/terminal_reporter.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-3.8.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-3.8.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-3.8.0/boot.js"></script>
  <script src="../reporter/reporterRunner.js"></script>


  <script src="../js/utils.js"></script>
  <script src="spec/UtilsSpec.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It works too but output goes to the browser console, not in the terminal.
Tell, me please, how to manage jasmine to show nice results in the terminal console?
Maybe jasmine-browser-runner could work with terminal reporters somehow?